# Split a list into a target element, and the rest of the list?

Tags: scala, playframework, functional-programming

Let's say I have something like the following:

```
case class Thing(num: Int)

val xs = List(Thing(1), Thing(2), Thing(3))
```

What I'd like to do is separate the list into one particular value, and the rest of the list. The target value can be at any position in the list, or may not be present at all. The single value needs to be handled separately, after the other values are handled, so I can't simply use pattern matching.

What I have so far is this:

```
val (targetList, rest) = xs.partition(_.num == 2)

val targetEl = targetList match {
    case x :: Nil => x
    case _ => null
}
```

Is it possible to combine the two steps? Like

```
val (targetEl, rest) = xs.<some_method>
```

*A note on handling order:*
The reason that the target element must be handled last is that this is for use in a HTML template (Play framework). The other elements are looped through, and a HTML element is rendered for each. After that group of elements, another HTML element is created for the target element.

Answer (score 3):

You *can* do it with pattern-matching in `map`, you just need multiple cases:

```
xs map {
    case t @ Thing(1) => // do something with thing 1
    case t => // do something with the other things
}
```

To handle the OP's extra requirements:

```
xs map {
    case t @ Thing(num) if(num != 1) => // do something with things that are not "1"
    case t => // do something with thing 1
}
```

Comment: This is an informative answer, but unfortunately, the target element needs to be handled strictly after the other elements.

Comment: @evanjdooner You can still use `map` and pattern-matching. You just need to change the order and match expressions. Other than writing your own method to do this, you won't find something that does exactly this by a unique name in the standard library, because these requirements are very specific.

Comment: I think there should be `case t @ Thing(num) if num != 1 =>` in the second  example

Comment: @Odomontois Yeah, it was a typo. A clear case against copy and pasting code.

Answer (score 1):

Following produces two lists as tuples for some condition.

```
case class Thing(num: Int)

val xs = List(Thing(1), Thing(2), Thing(3))

val partioned = xs.foldLeft((List.empty[Thing], List.empty[Thing]))((x, y) => y match {
  case t @ Thing(1) => (x._1, t :: x._2)
  case t            => (t :: x._1, x._2)
})
//(List(Thing(3), Thing(2)),List(Thing(1)))
```

Comment: Nice! That's similar to the answer I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
val (targetEl, rest) = (xs.head, xs.tail)
```

It works for non-empty list. Nil case must be handled separately.

Comment: Sorry if my example wasn't clear, but the target element can be at an arbitrary position in the list. This answer only works when the target element is the first element in the list. I'll update my example to clarify it.

Comment: `List#tail` is a partial function. There's certainly a better alternative. Otherwise, there's a run-time exception risk.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation, I've come up with the following, which is almost what I'm looking for:

```
var (maybeTargetEl, rest) = xs
    .foldLeft((Option.empty[Thing], List[Thing]())) { case ((opt, ls), x) => 
      if (x.num == 1)
        (Some(x), ls)
      else
        (opt, x :: ls) 
    }
```

The target value is still wrapped in a container, but at least it guarantees a single value.

After that I can do

```
rest map <some_method>
maybeTargetEl map <some_other_method>
```

If the order of the original list is important:

```
var (maybeTargetEl, rest) = xs.
  foldLeft((Option.empty[Thing], ListBuffer[Thing]())){ case ((opt, lb), x) => 
    if (x.num == 1)
      (Some(x), ls)
    else
      (opt, lb += x)
  } match {
    case (opt, lb) => (opt, lb.toList)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

@evanjdooner Your solution with fold works if target element is present only once. If you want to extract only one occurrence of target element:

`def find(xs: List[T], target: T, prefix: List[T]) = xs match {
     case target :: tail => (target, prefix ::: tail)
     case other :: tail => find(tail, target, other :: prefix)
     case Nil => throw new Exception("Not found")
}
val (el, rest) = find(xs, target, Nil)`

Sorry, I can't add it as a comment.